# Converting a 2d array to 2d vector of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have the following code and I'm trying to convert the two dimensional array to a two dimensional vector.

```
int main()
{
    const string ID_BASE = "56-123-";
    const int NUM_AISLES = 2;
    const int NUM_SHELVES = 3;

    // Declare 2-D array of objects.
    //Product products[NUM_AISLES][NUM_SHELVES];
    Product **products;

    int idNum = 0;
    int i, j;

    products = new Product *[NUM_AISLES];

   // Add a set of candy bars (all same price).
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_AISLES; i++)
   {
       products[i] = new Product[NUM_SHELVES];

        for (j = 0; j < NUM_SHELVES; j++)
        {
            // Build up id number using string stream.
            stringstream id;
            id << ID_BASE << setfill('0') << setw(2) << idNum;

            products[i][j].set(id.str(), 0.50, true);

            idNum++;
        }
    }

    // Increase prices and output each product.

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_AISLES; i++)
    {
        // Increase price for all products in aisle
        // (recall products is 2-d, but function
        // increasePrice() wants 1-d array).
       increasePrice(products[i], NUM_SHELVES, 1.0);

        for (j = 0; j < NUM_SHELVES; j++)
        {
            // Output individual product in 2-d array.
            products[i][j].output();
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }
```

Nearly all of my searches about multidimensional vectors are based on primitive data types, and the fact that I'm trying to create a two dimensional vector of objects is tripping me up. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Just use a `std::vector<std::vector<Product>>`

Comment: ... or `std::array<std::array<Product>>` if you do not need to resize

Comment: Okay so I changed it to `vector<vector<Product>> products;` and `products.push_back(vector<Product>());` in the outer for loop. This should work? I'm getting an error on products in the line `increasePrice(products[i], NUM_SHELVES, 1.0);` and I'm not sure what this should be.

Comment: if you call it like this, the function should be `void increasePrice(std::vector<Products>, ??,??)`

Comment: When I try `vector<Product>` I'm getting type name not allowed. `increasePrice` is defined as `void increasePrice(Product incrProds[], int numProds, double amt)`

Comment: `type name not allowed` sounds like you put the type on the function call.. However, without seeing the code its hard to say. Maybe later today I will find time to write a more comprehensive answer (or if you are lucky someone else will do it)

Answer (score 0):

I just give you a simple example of initializing a 2D Vector of objects and hope this will help you getting started:

```
#include <vector>
class Foo {};
typedef std::vector<Foo> FooVector;
typedef std::vector<FooVector> FooMatrix;
main(){
    FooMatrix X;
    for (int i=0;i<imax;i++){
        FooVector Y;
        for (int j=0;j<jmax;j++){
            Y.push_back(Foo());
        }
        X.push_back(Y);
    }
    // ... this is equivalent to ...
    FooMatrix X2 = FooMatrix(imax,FooVector(jmax,Foo()));
}
```

and if have a function that takes a vector:

```
void bar(FooVector x,int y){ /*...*/ }
```

you can call it like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<X2.size();i++){
     bar(X2[i],i);
     // ... or ...
     bar(X2.at(i),i);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

Use a two dimensional vector:

1) you could use `vector<vector<Product *>>` products;

```
vector<vector<Product *> > products;

products[i].push_back(new Product());
```

Remember to release the objects once done via pointers.

2) you could use `vector<vector<Product>>` products;

```
products[i].push_back(Product());
```

If you decide to store them by pointers, you  must manage allocation/deallocation of these objects.

There are many other things to be taken care of:
[vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460377/why-is-using-vector-of-pointers-considered-bad)

On the other hand, storing object by copies in  vectors will provide a better locality of reference.

Comment: No. Dont do this. Why do you want to store pointers and not simply the objects? There is no need to use `new` and `delete`

Comment: A) just dont allocate via `new` B) the vector stores copies, so putting a heap allocated object in a vector does not change anything about how you have to delete it. The vector will delete its copy but the original you still have to delete on you own. C) just dont allocate via `new`

Comment: I do not understand why you deleted your comment (and by this kind of invalidated mine). And btw `vector<vector<Product>> products; products[i].push_back(Product());` will compile but crash!